# What is the <%= syntax in the Angular2-Seed project?

Tags: gulp, angular

I see a bunch of <% and <%= in the Angular2-Seed project, what is it? Is it an Angular2 thing, or a Gulp thing, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably the gulp template plugin. See:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-template

and in the angular2-seed project you can see it being invoked in:

```
tools/tasks/seed/build.index.dev.ts
```

The following is an extract from that file:

```
export = () => {
  return gulp.src(join(APP_SRC, 'index.html'))
    .pipe(inject('shims'))
    .pipe(inject('libs'))
    .pipe(inject())
    .pipe(plugins.template(templateLocals())) <-- HERE
    .pipe(gulp.dest(APP_DEST));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks devilishly similar to ASP....

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/showasp.asp?filename=demo_text

`<%` would be opening server side asp code.

`<%=` is directly printing the server side e.g `<% print("Something"); %>` -> `<%=print("something");%>`

---

Looking at the link added in the comments by jz87 you'll see the code snipplet

```
  <% if (ENV === 'dev') { %>
  <script>System.config(<%= JSON.stringify(SYSTEM_CONFIG) %>)</script>

  <script>
    System.import('<%= BOOTSTRAP_MODULE %>')
      .catch(function (e) {
        console.error(e,
          'Report this error at https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/issues');
      });
  </script>
  <% } %>
```

It seems to be that the <% %> does indicate a 'server side code' or code that is executed prior to the page being rendered by the browser (this is how JSP, ASP, and PHP work). The language being used, I would guess is ECMAScript 6 (JavaScript).

So I would guess that you are looking at JavaScript server side code snippets within the <% %>

Comment: Agree. Must be some kind of "proper" code. Also similar to JSP scriplets.

Comment: Except this has nothing to do with ASP. Take a look at this https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/blob/master/app/index.html

Comment: I edited my response according to your link. Keep in mind this is just an educated guess